# Date difference and imputation of date

Tags: r, date

I have two columns, `Invoice_date` and `due_date`. If `due_date>Invoice_date` replace all those values of `due_date` with `Invoice_date` else it should be the same `due_date`. However, I am not getting the result. Below is the code in R. Please help if the below code is correct logically.

```
Data$INVOICE_DATE1 <- ifelse((as.Date(Data$DUE_DATE) - as.Date(Data$INVOICE_DATE)) <= 0, 
                               as.Date(Data$INVOICE_DATE), as.Date(Data$DUE_DATE))
```

Comment: What you say you want and what your code does are two completely different things. Read your question again carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ifelse` you could use the more straightfoward `case_when` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

# This creates a new column as in your example
Data %>%
    mutate(INVOICE_DATE1 = case_when(
           DUE_DATE > INVOICE_DATE ~ INVOICE_DATE,
           TRUE ~ DUE_DATE))

# This replaces due date as in your description
Data %>%
    mutate(DUE_DATE= case_when(
           DUE_DATE > INVOICE_DATE ~ INVOICE_DATE,
           TRUE ~ DUE_DATE))
```

If you want to stick to your old structure you need to implement `apply` to iterate over all elements of your vector in the `ifelse`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However i still have duedates <invoicedate. Logic are fine but i am not getting the result.

Comment: when i take the datedifference(duedate-invoice date) there are negative values

Comment: @YogeshGovindan then you need to provide some sample data via ```dput(DATA)```please post the output of that function in your question. If its too big, you can also use ```dput(head(DATA))``` to only include the first 6 rows.